# Any java static/dynamic code analyze tool to find all recursive method in my java project

Tags: java

I need to find all recursive methods in my projects (100+ eclipse java/plugin projects with about ~1 millions lines of code) since we found some performance problems caused by recursive methods. We don't care about the used libraries.

I would prefer open source/free and with eclipse plug-ins. Static code analyzer would be even better.

Findbug or google's codepro seems don't have such function. Also check style, PMD, etc...

Any one know such tool, or give some hint to write such a feature?

Comment: are you looking for simple recursion (ie a method that calls itself) or complex chains that build call loops? The first would be trivial using ASM or such. The later is bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, currently start from simple recursion. ASM or javasist should work, but is my last choice if there is no existing tool to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree here.

It is fallacious to conclude from 'some' performance problems that are due to a recursion that all recursions are causing all your performance problems.

You must already have a way of looking for performance problems. So look for performance problems, not recursive methods. If the performance problem is due to a recursive method, fix that. If it is due to something else, fix that. That way you have fixed everything you need to fix and nothing you don't need to fix.

Comment: +1. Recursion is not the problem. Recursion is more efficient and vastly simpler for many algorithms.

Comment: @Amir Afghani Did you leave out a ;-)?

Comment: I totally agree with you that recursion is not the problem and needed for many algorithms, and i don't want to change them to use stack.But  recursions may be  one of the root cause of some performance problem  and I just want to find them all from about 1 million lines of code and do some manual checking. This is more like static analyze instead of dynamic analyze.  Another way is if we found a performance problem, profile it and fix it.  If there is no existing tool to easily find all recursive methods, i will use the find and fix way.And when have enough time,write a small tool...

Comment: I have to type all this stuff before I can ;)

Comment: Ben. instead of hunting down what could be a performance bottleneck, use the standard methodologies that exist to find REAL bottlenecks (using profilers, top ten contributers, etc)

Comment: Thanks, I will try other way first.

Comment: @Ben Xu you are just contradicting yourself. Either you are trying to solve performance problems, in which case your tool is a profiler, or you are off on a wild goose chase.

Comment: from short-term, using a profile tool such as Yourkit can solve problem.  from long-term, if continue found recursive caused problem, make a small tool is needed since can not find one. this is why i say "try other way first:-)"

Comment: @Ben Xu apparently you haven't understood a word I've said. Your problem isn't recursion. It is performance. So solve that. With the tools you already have. The investigation into recursion on its own is completely and utterly pointless. Recursion isn't a problem, it is a perfectly valid programming technique. The JDK is full of it.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why you call  find recuresion is "on a wild goose chase" now :)